# Libgdx and Google Play Billing

Tags: android, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, android-billing

I am using Libgdx + Android Studio and trying to implement Google Play Billing. I follow the instructions from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_java_kotlin#java).
I modify my dependencies as it is shown in te example:

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'}
```

So my build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'




}
}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "Test"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    jcenter()
}
}

project(":desktop") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'

}
}

project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi- 
v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64- 
v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
}
}

project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'

}
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
delete ".project"
}
```

The problem is when I try to use the code from example I get errors.
For this code

```
private BillingClient mBillingClient;
```

I get the error "Cannot find symbol class BillingClient". When I try to do this:

```
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient;
```

I get the error "package com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient does not exist".

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use gdx-pay?

Answer (score 1):

```
com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1
```

Google Play Billing library is for android so remove from other module dependency section. You can use [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) to access platform specific APIs.

---

However [gdx-pay](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay) is a Libgdx extension library for handling in-app purchases in a cross-platform way.